# SQL code to find the top 6

Tags: sql

Write SQL code to find the **top 6** Client Country for each company.

[image]

How to approach this query? So far I am thinking:-

```
select top 6 Client_Country, count(*) Total
from table group by Client_Country
order by total desc
```

Comment: By top do you mean highest revenue?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server / MySQL / etc)?

Comment: I think its fair to say OP is using sql server, tho, you really should tag it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the top for each country, you'll need to use a windowing function. Otherwise, you'll just get the top 6 overall.

I'm not sure what RDBMS you're using, but in SQL Server you can do something like this:

```
;WITH top_cte AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Revenue DESC) AS [Rank]
  FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM top_cte
WHERE [Rank] <= 6
```

EDIT: Edited to use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK`. The one issue with `RANK` is that if you had, say, 3 companies tied for 5th place, you'd get 8 results back instead of 6.

Comment: Not if it's at the beginning of a block, you don't -- I leave it out all the time. And if it isn't at the beginning of a block, it's more appropriate to end your previous statement with a semi-colon than begin this one with it. But since I know that's pretty common around here, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *,Row_Number() Over(Partition By Company Order By (Select Null)) RN FROM TAble1
) AS T
Where RN < 7
```

Comment: Based on my understanding of the question, I don't think you'd want to partition by `Client_Country`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use a rank() function to get this working, then CTE to restrict it to the top 6 , something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT company,client_company, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY REVENUE DESC) as top6
    FROM table
) k
WHERE k.top6<7
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
;with cte as
(
select *,rn=dense_rank()over(partition by company order by Revenue desc) from table
)

select top 6 with ties * from cte
```

`with ties` lets you select in case of ties

Comment: Your query isn't referencing the `rn` field, which means it will only return 6 records, not 6 per company. In making that change, you'll also need to change `dense_rank`, because after you add `rn` to the `WHERE` clause, it could potentially return far more than 6 records per company.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 6 Company, Client_Country, Revenue FROM table where Revenue = (select max(Revenue) from Revenue i where i.Client_Country= table.Client_Country) order by Revenue desc;

Am I on right track?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 6 CLIENT_COUNTRY, COMPANY 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COMPANY
ORDER BY REVENUE DESC
```

It depends on your RDBMS, use :

`TOP` :SQL server, MS Access
`LIMIT`: MySQL
`ROWNUM` : Oracle

Comment: This will provide the top 6 overall, not the top for each company. This query needs a windowing function.